# Spring boot JPA how to query filter on @Transient attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot 1.3.3 with starter-data-jpa + I am using [specification-arg-resolver](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver) for combine multiple filters in JPA Repo

I have a filed call status attribute in entity which is matching to the database status id, nevertheless, we want search by status name, I defined all the status name in hashMap of the entity it is like following code

However when I try to filter by status name I got

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [statusName] on this ManagedType [api.domain.Inscription]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [statusName] on this ManagedType [api.domain.Inscription]] with root cause
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [statusName] on this ManagedType [api.domain.Inscription]

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="INSCRIPTIONS")
public class Inscription {
    private static final Map<Byte, String> STATUS = new HashMap<Byte, String>(){{
       put((byte) 1, "sale");
       put((byte) 3, "rent");
    }};

    private byte status;

    @Transient
    private String statusName;

    public byte getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(byte status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatusName() {
        return STATUS.get(this.status);
    }

    public void setStatusName(byte status) {
        this.statusName = STATUS.get(status);
    }
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```
 public class InscriptionController
 {
     @Autowired
     private InscriptionRepository inscriptionRepository;

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public Page<Inscription> findAll(
     final @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0", required = false) int offset,
     final @RequestParam(defaultValue = "20", required = false) int limit,
     @Spec(params = "status",  path = "statusName", spec = In.class) Specification<Inscription> spec
 )
 {
     Page<Inscription> inscriptions = inscriptionRepository.findAll(spec, new PageRequest(offset, limit));
     return inscriptions;
 }
```

**Repo Class:**

```
public interface InscriptionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Inscription, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Inscription> { }
```

Comment: Why do you put @Transient on it when you don't want it?

Comment: @mh-dev Because statusName is not exist in table, status is exist but it is the id of status, I would like to filter by the status name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for @Rafik BELDI I did it with specification, hope this can help anyone have the same problem a little bit.

**Spec class**

```
public class InscriptionSpecification
{
     public static Specification<Inscription> statusNameIn(String[] statusNames) {
        if (statusNames == null || statusNames.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Inscription inscription = new Inscription();
            List<Byte> statusIds = new ArrayList<Byte>();
            for (String oneStatusName : statusNames) {
                statusIds.add(inscription.getStatusIdByName(oneStatusName));
            }
            return cb.isTrue(root.<String>get("status").in(statusIds));
        };
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public Page<Inscription> findAll(
       final @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0", required = false) int offset,
       final @RequestParam(defaultValue = "20", required = false) int limit,
       final @RequestParam(required = false) String[] status
   )
   {
       Specification<Inscription> specStatusNameIn = InscriptionSpecification.statusNameIn(status);
       inscriptionRepository.findAll(specStatusNameIn, new PageRequest(offset, limit));
       return inscriptions;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`@Transient` annotation is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database, which means it has no equivalent in the database and you can't query over it.

And since `statutName` is related to `status` which is not transiet , you can use `status` instead.

Comment: But as I explained in the question statusName is not in database status does. However status is the id in database. I want them pass string (ex. rent) instead of id. How can I do that ?

Comment: @zt1983811 you can't pass the string to the database , it has no meaning , convert it to status and query over status that's your only way to do it

Comment: Yes I knew that I just read how to do the Specification or Querydsl. I will post an answer soon.

Comment: @zt1983811 no matter what  method you use you will endup querying over STATUS.I use both querydsl and specifications , all what you can do is to pass statusName and retrieve its equivalent from STATUS and query the db over status.

Comment: Yes @Rafik BELDI that's what I am goona do, which one you are suggest more Specifications or querydsl ?

Comment: @zt1983811 if you do it without passing through the classe primary key plz keep me updated :)